# Cant send message by outlook, roundcube works

Tags: centos, centos6, dovecot, exim, sieve

I have some problem with dovecot, I have added dovecot_lda support for roundcube sieve filters. Roundcube works perfectly with the filters now. 
But if i try send messages by smtp (outlook|thunderbird), the mail client ask always pass and doesnt pass to  send email.

```
/var/log/exim/main.log:
2015-09-17 20:53:08 dovecot_plain authenticator failed for hostname.domain.com ([192.168.0.2]) [1.1.1.1]: 435 Unable to authenticate at present: authentication socket connection error
```

-

```
[root@alfa ~]# cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-master.conf

service imap-login {
  inet_listener imap {
  }
  inet_listener imaps {
  }
}

service pop3-login {
  inet_listener pop3 {
  }
  inet_listener pop3s {
  }
}


service imap {
}

service pop3 {
}

service auth {
  unix_listener auth-userdb {
    group = mail
    mode = 0660
    user = dovecot
  }
  user = dovecot
}
```

-

```
    [root@alfa ~]# cat /etc/exim/exim.conf
######################################################################
#                                                                    #
#          Exim configuration file for Vesta Control Panel           #
#                                                                    #
######################################################################

SPAMASSASSIN = yes
SPAM_SCORE = 50
CLAMD =  yes

domainlist local_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim/domains/
domainlist relay_to_domains = dsearch;/etc/exim/domains/
hostlist relay_from_hosts = 127.0.0.1
hostlist whitelist = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim/white-blocks.conf
hostlist spammers = net-iplsearch;/etc/exim/spam-blocks.conf
no_local_from_check
untrusted_set_sender = *
acl_smtp_connect = acl_check_spammers
acl_smtp_mail = acl_check_mail
acl_smtp_rcpt = acl_check_rcpt
acl_smtp_data = acl_check_data
acl_smtp_mime = acl_check_mime

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
spamd_address = 127.0.0.1 783
.endif

.ifdef CLAMD
av_scanner = clamd: /var/run/clamav/clamd.sock
.endif

tls_advertise_hosts = *
tls_certificate = /usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.crt
tls_privatekey = /usr/local/vesta/ssl/certificate.key

daemon_smtp_ports = 25 : 465 : 587 : 2525
tls_on_connect_ports = 465
never_users = root
host_lookup = *
rfc1413_hosts = *
rfc1413_query_timeout = 5s
ignore_bounce_errors_after = 2d
timeout_frozen_after = 7d

DKIM_DOMAIN = ${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}
DKIM_FILE = /etc/exim/domains/${lc:${domain:$h_from:}}/dkim.pem
DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY = ${if exists{DKIM_FILE}{DKIM_FILE}{0}}



######################################################################
#                       ACL CONFIGURATION                            #
#         Specifies access control lists for incoming SMTP mail      #
######################################################################
begin acl

acl_check_spammers:
  accept  hosts         = +whitelist

  drop    message       = Your host in blacklist on this server.
          log_message   = Host in blacklist
          hosts         = +spammers

  accept


acl_check_mail:
  deny    condition     = ${if eq{$sender_helo_name}{}}
          message       = HELO required before MAIL

  drop    message       = Helo name contains a ip address (HELO was $sender_helo_name) and not is valid
          condition     = ${if match{$sender_helo_name}{\N((\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3}[.-]\d{1,3})|([0-9a-f]{8})|([0-9A-F]{8}))\N}{yes}{no}}
          condition     = ${if match {${lookup dnsdb{>: defer_never,ptr=$sender_host_address}}\}{$sender_helo_name}{no}{yes}}
          delay         = 45s

  drop    condition     = ${if isip{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.3)

  drop    condition     = ${if eq{[$interface_address]}{$sender_helo_name}}
          message       = $interface_address is _my_ address

  accept


acl_check_rcpt:
  accept  hosts         = :

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = +local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[.] : ^.*[@%!/|]

  deny    message       = Restricted characters in address
          domains       = !+local_domains
          local_parts   = ^[./|] : ^.*[@%!] : ^.*/\\.\\./

  require verify        = sender

  accept  hosts         = +relay_from_hosts
          control       = submission

  accept  authenticated = *
          control       = submission/domain=

  deny    message       = Rejected because $sender_host_address is in a black list at $dnslist_domain\n$dnslist_text
          hosts         = !+whitelist
          dnslists      = ${readfile {/etc/exim/dnsbl.conf}{:}}

  require message       = relay not permitted
          domains       = +local_domains : +relay_to_domains

  deny    message       = smtp auth requried
         sender_domains = +local_domains
         !authenticated = *

  require verify        = recipient

.ifdef CLAMD
  warn    set acl_m0    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antivirus}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m0    = yes
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn    set acl_m1    = no

  warn    condition     = ${if exists {/etc/exim/domains/$domain/antispam}{yes}{no}}
          set acl_m1    = yes
.endif

  accept


acl_check_data:
.ifdef CLAMD
  deny   message        = Message contains a virus ($malware_name) and has been rejected
         malware        = *
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m0}{yes}{yes}{no}}
.endif

.ifdef SPAMASSASSIN
  warn   !authenticated = *
         hosts          = !+relay_from_hosts
         condition      = ${if < {$message_size}{100K}}
         condition      = ${if eq{$acl_m1}{yes}{yes}{no}}
         spam           = nobody:true/defer_ok
         add_header     = X-Spam-Score: $spam_score_int
         add_header     = X-Spam-Bar: $spam_bar
         add_header     = X-Spam-Report: $spam_report
         set acl_m2     = $spam_score_int

  warn   condition      = ${if !eq{$acl_m2}{} {yes}{no}}
         condition      = ${if >{$acl_m2}{SPAM_SCORE} {yes}{no}}
         add_header     = X-Spam-Status: Yes
         message        = SpamAssassin detected spam (from $sender_address to $recipients).
.endif

  accept


acl_check_mime:
  deny   message        = Blacklisted file extension detected
         condition      = ${if match {${lc:$mime_filename}}{\N(\.ade|\.adp|\.bat|\.chm|\.cmd|\.com|\.cpl|\.exe|\.hta|\.ins|\.isp|\.jse|\.lib|\.lnk|\.mde|\.msc|\.msp|\.mst|\.pif|\.scr|\.sct|\.shb|\.sys|\.vb|\.vbe|\.vbs|\.vxd|\.wsc|\.wsf|\.wsh)$\N}{1}{0}}

  accept



######################################################################
#                   AUTHENTICATION CONFIGURATION                     #
######################################################################
begin authenticators

dovecot_plain:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = PLAIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1

dovecot_login:
  driver = dovecot
  public_name = LOGIN
  server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
  server_set_id = $auth1



######################################################################
#                      ROUTERS CONFIGURATION                         #
#               Specifies how addresses are handled                  #
######################################################################
begin routers

#smarthost:
#  driver = manualroute
#  domains = ! +local_domains
#  transport = remote_smtp
#  route_list = * smartrelay.vestacp.com
#  no_more
#  no_verify


dnslookup:
  driver = dnslookup
  domains = !+local_domains
  transport = remote_smtp
  no_more

userforward:
  driver = redirect
  check_local_user
  file = $home/.forward
  allow_filter
  no_verify
  no_expn
  check_ancestor
  file_transport = address_file
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  reply_transport = address_reply

procmail:
  driver = accept
  check_local_user
  require_files = ${local_part}:+${home}/.procmailrc:/usr/bin/procmail
  transport = procmail
  no_verify

autoreplay:
  driver = accept
  require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg
  condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg}}{yes}{no}}
  retry_use_local_part
  transport = userautoreply
  unseen

aliases:
  driver = redirect
  headers_add = X-redirected: yes
  data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}
  require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases
  redirect_router = dnslookup
  pipe_transport = address_pipe
  unseen

localuser_fwd_only:
  driver = accept
  transport = devnull
  condition = ${if exists{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/fwd_only}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/fwd_only}{true}{false}}}}

localuser_spam:
  driver = accept
  transport = local_spam_delivery
  condition = ${if eq {${if match{$h_X-Spam-Status:}{\N^Yes\N}{yes}{no}}} {${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}{yes}{no_such_user}}}}

localuser:
driver = accept
#transport = local_delivery
transport = dovecot
condition = ${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}{true}{false}}

catchall:
  driver = redirect
  headers_add = X-redirected: yes
  require_files = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases
  data = ${extract{1}{:}{${lookup{*@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}}}}
  file_transport = local_delivery
  redirect_router = dnslookup

terminate_alias:
  driver = accept
  transport = devnull
  condition = ${lookup{$local_part@$domain}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/aliases}{true}{false}}



######################################################################
#                      TRANSPORTS CONFIGURATION                      #
######################################################################
begin transports

dovecot:
driver = pipe
command = /usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -e -d $local_part@$domain -f $sender_address -a $original_local_part@$original_domain
return_path_add
log_output = true
delivery_date_add
envelope_to_add
user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}
group = mail
return_output

remote_smtp:
  driver = smtp
  #helo_data = $sender_address_domain
  dkim_domain = DKIM_DOMAIN
  dkim_selector = mail
  dkim_private_key = DKIM_PRIVATE_KEY
  dkim_canon = relaxed
  dkim_strict = 0

procmail:
  driver = pipe
  command = "/usr/bin/procmail -d $local_part"
  return_path_add
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  user = $local_part
  initgroups
  return_output

local_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  maildir_format
  maildir_use_size_file
  user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}
  group = mail
  create_directory
  directory_mode = 770
  mode = 660
  use_lockfile = no
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}/mail/$domain/$local_part"
  quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}M
  quota_warn_threshold = 75%

local_spam_delivery:
  driver = appendfile
  maildir_format
  maildir_use_size_file
  user = ${extract{2}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}
  group = mail
  create_directory
  directory_mode = 770
  mode = 660
  use_lockfile = no
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add
  directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}/mail/$domain/$local_part/.Spam"
  quota = ${extract{6}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}M
  quota_directory = "${extract{5}{:}{${lookup{$local_part}lsearch{/etc/exim/domains/$domain/passwd}}}}/mail/$domain/$local_part"
  quota_warn_threshold = 75%

address_pipe:
  driver = pipe
  return_output

address_file:
  driver = appendfile
  delivery_date_add
  envelope_to_add
  return_path_add

address_reply:
  driver = autoreply

userautoreply:
  driver = autoreply
  file = /etc/exim/domains/$domain/autoreply.${local_part}.msg
  from = "${local_part}@${domain}"
  subject = "${if def:h_Subject: {Autoreply: ${quote:${escape:$h_Subject:}}} {Autoreply Message}}"
  to = "${sender_address}"

devnull:
  driver = appendfile
  file = /dev/null

######################################################################
#                      RETRY CONFIGURATION                           #
######################################################################
begin retry

# Address or Domain    Error       Retries
# -----------------    -----       -------
*                      *           F,2h,15m; G,16h,1h,1.5; F,4d,6h



######################################################################
#                      REWRITE CONFIGURATION                         #
######################################################################
begin rewrite



######################################################################
```

-

```
[root@alfa ~]# cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf
protocol lda {
mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
postmaster_address = user@domain
log_path = /var/log/dovecot-lda.log
}
```

-

```
[root@alfa ~]# cat /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf
plugin {
    sieve = /var/mail/virtual/%u/sieve/dovecot.sieve
    sieve_global_path = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
    sieve_dir = /var/mail/virtual/%u/sieve
    sieve_global_dir = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/sieve/global/
}
```

-

How the problem can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because dovecot, by default, does not trust plain text authentication coming from hosts different than 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

You can solve the problem using two different solutions:

1. switch your Outlook client to use SSL protocols (IMAPS:port 993 / SMTPS: ports 465 or 587). **This is the best approach**
2. enable plain authentication for your Outlook client's network using the `login_trusted_networks` directive

Comment: 587 and ssl doesnt help, tested in thunderbird.

Comment: Is selinux enabled? If so, try to disable it using the command `setenforce 0` and re-try to autenticate.

Comment: SELINUX=disabled
It was already disables